# git add hook / getting git to ignore file modes of new files

Tags: windows, git, commit, chmod, githooks

I'm working with a git repository on both windows and linux/mac.  When I create new files on windows, or edit them in some text editors, the file mode is changed to 775.  I can get git to ignore file mode changes with

```
git config core.filemode false
```

but I also want most new files to have mode 664 (not 775).  The best I've come up with so far is the pre-commit hook

```
git diff --cached --name-only | egrep -v '\.(bat|py|sh|exe)' | xargs -d"\n" chmod 664
git diff --cached --name-only | egrep -v '\.(bat|py|sh|exe)' | xargs -d"\n" git add
```

but this does the wrong thing if I've added a new file, then edited it again before commiting, and then commited without adding it.  Is there a better way to do this, or something like a pre-add or post-add hook?

Edit: `git diff --cached --name-only` also gives me files that have been deleted, so what I really want is something like `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `chmod` and readding, you can use `git update-index --chmod=-x <files>` to modify the index directly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at git attributes. You can handle it there. Smudge/clean may be a way to deal with it.

Comment: Smudge and clean seem to be filters that act on the contents of the file.  Is there a way to make them act on the metadata?  (Setting the clean operation to chmod -x gives an error.)